# SQL server: the version number in the package is not valid. the version number cannot be greater than current

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have an old SSIS integration project that i can only open via import wizard in Visual Studio 2019. I have tried in VS10,12,13,15,17 and i wont open.

My problem is when i deploy the project to the SQL server the server comes up with the error: the version number in the package is not valid. the version number cannot be greater than current. Can anyone help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, you have SSIS 2012, and try to start the package that is created for higher version of SSIS.
To fix it, open your SSIS project in Visual Studio, select Project and go to menu *Project - Properties*. Then on Project Properties window, select *Configuration Properties - General* and
[image]

select ***SQL Server 2012*** in the *TargetServerVersion* dropdown.
Hit Ok, save and build/deploy project again.